# Azure Pipeline cannot execute command after go get

Tags: go, azure-pipelines

I want to use `rsrc` to set an icon in my windows Go application in my azure devops pipeline.
I think I miss something trivial, my pipeline doesn't find the command `rsrc` after `go get -u -v github.com/akavel/rsrc`.

My workaround is to work with an rsrc.exe in the vcs.

#### Pipeline

```
  - task: Go@0
    displayName: Install rsrc
    condition: eq(variables['agent.os'], 'Windows_NT')
    inputs:
      command: 'get'
      arguments: '-u -v github.com/akavel/rsrc'
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) 


  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Generate syso files
    timeoutInMinutes: 1
    condition: eq(variables['agent.os'], 'Windows_NT')
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $icon = ([System.IO.Path]::Combine("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)", "build/App.ico"))
        $iconSyso = ([System.IO.Path]::Combine("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)", "cmd/myapp/rsrc.syso"))
        rsrc.exe -ico $icon -o $iconSyso
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

#### Error

**rsrc.exe** : The term 'rsrc.exe' is **not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program**.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

#### Update

1. `go install github.com/akavel/rsrc` doesn't help
2. `$env:GOPATH` is empty

Comment: Not familiar with Azure Pipelines but I think the issue is that `go get` installs `rsrc.exe` in `%GOPATH%\bin` which is not in `%PATH%` so in `PowerShell@2` task you probably need to give it full path (or set %PATH% to contain %GOPATH%)?

Comment: Also you can try `go install` since `go get` will not always install the program. %GOPATH%\bin has to be added to the %PATH% variable, as @blami said.

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer below can help you and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your error:

[image]

The way I solve this question is:

Firstly, before you run the Go task, you should set up `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` in advance.

Here is an example.

```
variables:
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)\bin' # Go binaries path
  GOPATH: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)\gopath' # Go workspace path
  modulePath: '$(GOPATH)\src\github.com\$(build.repository.name)' # Path to the module's code
```

Then add the `GOBIN` to the `PATH`.

```
- script: echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOBIN)'
```

So the complete script should be like this:

```
variables:
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)\bin' # Go binaries path
  GOPATH: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\gopath' # Go workspace path
  modulePath: '$(GOPATH)\src\github.com\$(build.repository.name)' # Path to the module's code

steps:
- task: Go@0
  displayName: Install rsrc
  condition: eq(variables['agent.os'], 'Windows_NT')
  inputs:
    command: 'get'
    arguments: '-u -v github.com/akavel/rsrc'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) 

- script: echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOBIN)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Generate syso files
  timeoutInMinutes: 1
  condition: eq(variables['agent.os'], 'Windows_NT')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $icon = ([System.IO.Path]::Combine("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)", "build/App.ico"))
      $iconSyso = ([System.IO.Path]::Combine("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)", "cmd/myapp/rsrc.syso"))
      rsrc.exe -ico $icon -o $iconSyso
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```